# How to rotate screen in landscape orientation using AVPlayerViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I am using autolayout and in a screen I create AVPlayerViewController with half the size of main view. I am using UITabBarViewController and UINavigationController. This screen is navigated from first child ViewController of UITabBarViewController. Code is like this..

```
    avPlayerVideoController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];

    avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoURL]];

    avPlayerVideoController.view.frame = CGRectMake( imgViewVideo.frame.origin.x, imgViewVideo.frame.origin.y, imgViewVideo.frame.size.width, imgViewVideo.frame.size.height);
    avPlayerVideoController.delegate = self;
    avPlayerVideoController.showsPlaybackControls = YES;
    avPlayerVideoController.player = avPlayer;
    [avPlayerVideoController.player play];
```

now I want the video to be rotated in landscape view when I click on that full screen button comes with AVPlayerViewController. It just remains in portrait orientation even I rotate my phone. And there is also no delegate method called when full screen button is tapped. Please I need this badly. Explain in detail how I should achieve this. Thank you

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Im also facing the same issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

add below code to your `viewController` with contains `AVPlayerViewController`

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

Hope it Helps you.

Comment: It didn't help me. When this method supportedInterfaceOrientations called? And I have used TabBarViewController. And this is the not the most top ViewController. It is navigated from the top lever ViewController.

Comment: @HirenPrajapati  your `AVPlayerViewController ` is added subview or presented?

Comment: oh my bad. In my project I only enabled portrait view. Btw AVPlayerViewController is added as subview. After enabling landscaped orientation from project, now I only want to change orientation when user clicks full screen button. How can I do this? Am I doing wrong? Just because of one screen should I turn on landscape orientation support? Because screen rotates in every ViewController.

Comment: So after understanding issue completely, now my question is by disabling landscape orientation support from project, how this added AVPlayerViewController in self.view can rotate to landscape when tapping full screen button?

Comment: yes this is right way to disabling landscape from project. but i can'w understand why are you adding AVPlayer as subview? why are you not presentining? can you please temm me for better understaing your issue

Answer (score 1):

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    [avPlayerLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
    [avPlayerLayer setFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```